# Language in index by .ist file

Tags: hyperref, makeindex

I've been indexing latex with the `imakeidx` package.
For this I have used the following code with a file `.ist` style.

Code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}            
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}               % Requerido para colores específicos
\usepackage{colortbl}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    % Teclado en español
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}      % Idioma del documento
\usepackage{calc}                     % espaciado en el index
\makeindex[options=-s StyleInd.ist] 

\begin{document}

the symbol \#\index{\#} should be in the the section "Símbolos".
And the number 9\index{9} should be in the sectiion "números"
Other index like tex\index{tex} was fine.


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice alfabético}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

StyleInd.ist:

```
delim_0 "\\dotfill\ "
delim_1 "\\dotfill\ "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\nopagebreak\n\\tikz\\node at (0pt,0pt) [draw=none,line width=1pt,inner sep=5pt]{\\parbox{\\linewidth-2\\fboxsep-2\\fboxrule-2pt}{\\centering\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries\\textcolor{white}{" heading_suffix "}}};\\vspace*{0.2cm}\\nopagebreak\n"
```

However, the name of the sections of the indexes appears in English and I need them in Spanish. As the other sections of the index appear with letters, I only need to change the language for the section name "symbols" and "numbers".

Thanks, and sorry for my english

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. By the way, the package `hyperref` had to be loaded lat in preamble (exceptional in some rare circumstances, which are not in your case).

Comment: You example does not compile.

Comment: By the way, I don't see sections, but try to load `babel` before `imakeidx`

Answer (score 3):

The names "Symbols" and "Numbers" are defined by the Makeindex style variables `symhead_positive` and `symhead_negative`. Add them to the `.ist` file:

```
symhead_positive "S\\'imbolos"
numhead_positive "N\\'umeros"
```

Also, the code sample of the question prints the headings with color white on the white default background. Maybe the contents of `heading_prefix` needs an update or the code sample is not complete.

Full example with some guessing and some fixes. In addition, the dependencies on packages `tikz` and `calc` are removed, and the calculation is performed using
e-TeX's `\dimexpr`.

```
% The default definition of environment "filecontents" does not
% overwrite an existing file.
% package "filecontents" redefines the environment in a way that it
% always writes the file.

% \RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{StyleInd.ist}
delim_0 "\\dotfill\ "
delim_1 "\\dotfill\ "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "
  \\begingroup
    \\setlength{\\fboxsep}{5pt}%
    \\colorbox{blue}{%
      \\color{white}\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries
      \\hbox to \\dimexpr\\linewidth-2\\fboxsep{%
        \\hfill "
heading_suffix "\\hfill
      }%
    }%
    \\nopagebreak\\vspace{2mm}%
  \\endgroup\n"
symhead_positive "S\\'imbolos"
numhead_positive "N\\'umeros"
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{color}               % Requerido para colores específicos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % Teclado en español
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}      % Idioma del documento
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{calc}                     % espaciado en el index
\makeindex[options=-s StyleInd.ist]
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

The symbol \#\index{\#} should be in the the section \enquote{Símbolos}
and the number 9\index{9} should be in the sectiion \enquote{números}.
Other index like tex\index{tex} was fine.

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice alfabético}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The index page:

> [image: Page 3]

Comment: How do you change the `\colorbox`es to rounded corner?

Comment: @pushpen.paul In short, packages like `tcolorbox` or TikZ help.

Comment: Where do I find full information about the style file `*.ist`? I found some info [here](https://wwwcdf.pd.infn.it/tex/latex/tex-refs/makeindex-style-file.html), but if there is an official place (URL or in TeXLive), it would be great.

Comment: @fishfin Makeindex has a [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/makeindex).